# java.lang.TypeNotPresentException

Tags: java, android, json, google-api

I'm using a fiew webservices that return an object but not a standard type object, it's an object of my own classes, for example:

```
public class BaseResponse {
    public String ErrorMessage;
    public String ResponseStatus;
    public String ResponseDate;
    public String SessionExpire;
}

public class ResponseJsonModel extends BaseResponse{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private boolean male;
    private Address address;
    ...
}
```

NOTE: BaseResponse is a standard types object.

 Everything works fine except when I use proguard because it throws:

```
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.myapp.ResponseJsonModel not present
```

I've found an issue similar to mine: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/issues/detail?id=527 but the solution doesn't work, I'm still having the same exception even if I use:

```
 -keep class com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonError$ErrorInfo
```

as mentioned in the issue...
I've read somewhere in the web that I should annotate such classes with various JAXB annotations. Could this be the solution? I know nothing about JAXB.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: how the BaseResponse look like ?

Comment: I've edited the question and added the BaseResponse

Comment: I've added a line to proguard-project.txt "-keep class <com.myapp.modelsfolder>** {*;} " and now the exception is not thrown. Could it be the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a line to proguard-project.txt `-keep class <com.myapp.modelsfolder>** {*;}` and now the exception is not thrown.